# Mysql to Google Chart with Column Label

Tags: php, mysql, label, google-visualization

I am trying to create a google chart with column labels. The following works just fine for me. Except that when i try to use it with a Json datacreated from a mysql table. Would you guys kindly help me out to understand where i am doing wrong.

Working Google Chart code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function drawVisualization() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['From', 'TotalOrders', 'Quantity'],
        ['Wk of 9/7/14', 172, 8910],
        ['Wk of 9/14/14', 121, 5901],
        ['Wk of 9/21/14', null, null],
        ['Wk of 9/28/14', null, null]
    ]);


    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat( {pattern:'#,###'});
    formatter.format(data, 1);
    formatter.format(data, 2);

    mydiv = $("#mychart");
    chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(mydiv[0]);
    chart.draw(data, {
        width: 600, height: 400, seriesType: 'bars',
        chartArea: {left: 60, top: 30, width: 540}
    });    


    rects = mydiv.find('svg > g > g > g > rect');
    var row = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {

        el = $(rects[i]);
        if (parseFloat(el.attr("height")) <= 2) { continue; }
        aparent = el.parent();
        do { // skips 'null' values
            text = data.getValue(row++, 1);
        } while (text == null && row < data.getNumberOfRows());

        if (text) {
            text = formatter.formatValue(text);
            // see below
            pos = getElementPos(el);
            attrs = {x: pos.x + pos.width / 2, y: pos.y - 2,
                fill: 'black',
                'font-family': 'Arial', 'font-size': 11,
                'text-anchor': 'middle'};
            aparent.append(addTextNode(attrs, text, aparent));
        }
    }
}


google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function getElementPos($el) {
    return {
        x: parseInt($el.attr("x")),
        width: parseInt($el.attr("width")),
        y: parseInt($el.attr("y")),
        height: parseInt($el.attr("height"))
    }
}


function addTextNode(attrs, text, _element) {
    var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "text");
    for (var k in attrs) { el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]); }
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
    el.appendChild(textNode);
    return el;
}

</script>
```

but when i use it with the following it doesn't work.

```
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'From', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'TotalOrders', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Quantity', 'type' => 'Number')
);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['From']); 
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['TotalOrders']); 
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Quantity']); 
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

I can't seem to find what is going wrong here. perhaps you guys will be able to point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

That JSON structure is not compatible with the `arrayToDataTable` function - you must use the regular DataTable constructor:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);
```

Also, you should have the `json_encode` function parse numbers correctly in the output, otherwise they may come out as strings:

```
$jsonTable = json_encode($table, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: I edited with both the suggestion. It gives a blank page as output. Did you try this and worked for you?

Comment: Is the page source blank?  If so, you have an error in your PHP that you need to track down.  If not, what is output by `echo $jsonTable;`?

Comment: This is exactly i am getting once i print jason. 


{"cols":[{"label":"From","type":"string"},{"label":"TotalOrders","type":"number"},{"label":"Quantity","type":"number"}],"0":["Owen","189","2096"],"Scott":["Jay","42","891"],"2":["Arnold","13","314"],"3":["Feng","976","2232"]}

Comment: There are two things wrong with that: first, you added your rows to the `$table['cols']` instead of `$table['rows']`, and second, you are missing the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` parameter in the `json_encode` function call.

Comment: are you talking about the line ' $table["cols"] = array( ' ? or '$table["rows"] = $rows;'

Comment: Your output has your rows inside the `$table['cols']` array, when they should be in `$table['rows']`, like it is coded in your question.